# Вставка JSON данных в MySQL Используя PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Такая ситуация 
Вот таким php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=333','root','');

$jsondata = file_get_contents('sob.json');

$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into country values(?,?)");

foreach ($data as $row) {

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Записывает то этот формат json Нормально

```
[
    {
        "id":"8192",
        "name":"Светлана"
    },

    {
        "id":"8193",
        "name":"Сергей"
    },
    {
        "id":"8194",
        "name":"Женя"
    },
    {
        "id":"8195",
        "name":"Слава"
    },

    {
        "id":"8196",
        "name":"Кирилл"
    }       
]
```

А вот этот у меня тупик Помогите

```
{
"status":"ok",
"data":[

    {
        "id":"8192",
        "name":"Светлана"
        "params":[
            {
                "name":"Тип автомобиля",
                "value":"С пробегом"
            },
            {
                "name":"Пробег, км",
                "value":"170 000 - 179 999"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id":"8193",
        "name":"Сергей"
        "params":[
            {
                "name":"Тип автомобиля",
                "value":"С пробегом"
            },

            {
                "name":"Пробег, км",
                "value":"170 000 - 179 999"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id":"8194",
        "name":"Женя"
        "params":[
            {
                "name":"Тип автомобиля",
                "value":"С пробегом"
            },
            {
                "name":"Пробег, км",
                "value":"170 000 - 179 999"
            }
        ] 
    }       
]
}
```

Comment: Что именно ставит Вас в тупик? Как обратиться к значениям params? Если да, то вот так: $data->data[0]->params[0]->name //Тип автомобиля

Comment: Как я понял, структуры базы у Вас еще нет. Ответ навскидку: PDO не может привязать массив к значению в запросе, ему нужно что-то, что может быть без проблем преобразовано в строку. Вам необходимо перед формированием PDO statement обработать $data так, чтобы получился одномерный массив. Судя по тому, что у Ваших сущностей есть свойство "params" (массив, из-за чего PDO не знает, как с ним поступить), стоит создать отдельную таблицу дня него - сначала записывать в одну таблицу id и name, затем в другую - params.name и params.value, а сами таблицы связать по id

Comment: @Firepro, `json_decode` для второго файла возвращает `null`.

Comment: @MaksimKlimenko он некорректный, везде после "name": "value" отсутствует запятая перед params, которая обязана там быть, чтобы разделять два поля, поэтому возвращается null

Comment: @Firepro, Да, уже вижу, ну вот в этом и проблема автора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, у вас не валидный `JSON`. Привожу отредактированный:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": [

        {
            "id": "8192",
            "name": "Светлана",
            "params": [{
                "name": "Тип автомобиля",
                "value": "С пробегом"
            }, {
                "name": "Пробег, км",
                "value": "170 000 - 179 999"
            }]


        },

        {
            "id": "8193",
            "name": "Сергей",
            "params": [{
                    "name": "Тип автомобиля",
                    "value": "С пробегом"
                },

                {
                    "name": "Пробег, км",
                    "value": "170 000 - 179 999"
                }
            ]


        },

        {
            "id": "8194",
            "name": "Женя",
            "params": [{
                "name": "Тип автомобиля",
                "value": "С пробегом"
            }, {
                "name": "Пробег, км",
                "value": "170 000 - 179 999"
            }]

        }

    ]
}
```

А цикл теперь будет выглядеть так:

```
foreach($data['data'] as $row) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо вот эти запятые.